# Why wouldn't breaking-retain-cycle fall into infinite-loop like this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Below is my code to verify the question.

## 0. Mock a retain-cycle

I create two classes, A & B:

```
@interface A : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) B *b;

@end

@implementation A

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_b release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

//

```
@interface B : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) A *a;

@end

@implementation B

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_a release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

// And in `StrongViewController`, there are tempA and tempB, which are both assign proprety:

```
@interface StrongViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) A *tempA;
@property (nonatomic, assign) B *tempB;

@end
```

// In `viewDidLoad`, I create the retain-cycle, a & b retain each other:

```
A *a = [[[A alloc] init] autorelease];
B *b = [[[B alloc] init] autorelease];

a.b = b;
b.a = a;

self.tempA = a;
self.tempB = b;
```

// Then in `viewWillDisappear`, I try to break the retain-cycle:

```
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
self.tempA.b = nil; // Key line
```

// Now, dive into the cycle step by step.

## 1. Using default setter to break retain-cycle

I set two breakpoints in A's dealloc & B's dealloc:

[image]
[image]

// Now when the key line `self.tempA.b = nil;` was executed:

[image]

// B's `dealloc` was called because `release` message was sent to b in A's `setB`:

[image]

[image]

// In B's `dealloc`, `release` message was sent to a, so A's `dealloc` was called then:

[image]

[image]

// Now, _b is `nil` because we use the default `setB:`, so it's okay to go through.

## 2. Using custom setter to break retain-cycle

// But what if using a custom `setB:` like below:

[image]

// When the key line `self.tempA.b = nil;` was executed, it runs into the custom `setB:`:

[image]

// Now `release` was sent to b, so it goes to B's `dealloc`:

// Notice that in B's `dealloc`, [self retainCount] is still 1, not 0, why?

[image]
[image]

// Here in B's `dealloc`, `release` was sent to _a, so it will go to A's `dealloc` in turn, and in there `release` will be sent to _b:

[image]
[image]

// Here comes the difference, in A's dealloc, `_b` is not nil, and _b's `retainCount` is 1.

// According to my knowledge, if _b receives a `release` message now, it will call its `dealloc` then, because its retainCount is 1 for the moment.

// But, out of my imagination, it doesn't step into B's `dealloc` recursively, but just step over to the next line, leaving the `retainCount` with a big value `2147483648`:

[image]

## 3. My question

// My question is on the above, why it step over when _b receives a `release` message, instead of stepping into its `dealloc`, while its `retainCount` is still **1** ?

// And how the retainCount `2147483648` comes out?

// To the depth, how the NSObject works when it receives a 'release' message indeed, anyone knows the source code? Even in A's `dealloc`, **a**'s retainCount` is still 1, so is **b**.

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com/ `retainCount` is not even useful for debugging purpose

Comment: The retain count is never decremented to 0 because there is no point in doing so.

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you release an object with a retain count of 1, the following happens:

The object is marked as "dead".

The dealloc method is called.

The memory of the object is returned to the OS.

retain and release have no effect when the object is marked as dead. The runtime doesn't even bother setting the retain count to zero before calling dealloc. When your second dealloc method gets called and tries to release an object that is already dead, even though retainCount returns 1, nothing happens. dealloc is never called twice for the same object.

Comment: Thanks, @gnasher729 . But the "dead" status must constrained to a scope, maybe in the `dealloc` method, right? Or, `Zombie messaged` won't happened. And for one step further, how do you know the information about "marked as dead" and etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm is worth checking out.

I think the problem has to do with hasCustomRR() but I find the code tricky to follow so could be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It is not to keep cyclic references between objects !!!
But it is required some time to use such references to get our task done.
So I will suggest if you have one of the object is dependent on other then you can make on of the reference WEAK.It will assure breaking cyclic looping of references. you can refer http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html tutorial for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks, but you are not answering the question. This topic is not about how to avoid retain-cycles, but about not falling into infinite-loop like above.

Comment: You know, I mock the retain-cycle on purpose.